# Number of ways to distribute $10$ different books to three children such that they get $3$, $3$ and $4$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Number of ways to distribute $10$ different books to three children such that one child gets $3$ books, another gets $3$ books and the other gets $4$ books.

We have the number of ways to distribute as

$$\binom{10}{3}\times \binom{7}{3} \times \binom{4}{4}=\frac{10!}{3!3!4!}$$

But I have doubt whether we need to multiply above answer with $\frac{3!}{2!}$ since the distribution $3, 3,4$ can arrange themselves in $\frac{3!}{2!}$ ways.

Comment: You are correct that we need the additional factor of $3$.  Letting our children be named Alice, Betty and Charles, the answer of $\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{4}$ is merely the number of ways Alice specifically gets three books, Betty specifically gets three books, and Charles specifically get four books.  It does not count scenarios where Alice was the one to get four books and the others three, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your worries are justified.

We have to select which child receives four books, which can be done in $3$ ways.  We select four of the ten books for that child, three of the remaining six books for the older of the other two children, and give the remaining three books to the other child who receives three books.  Thus, the number of ways the books may be distributed so that one child receives four books and two children each receive three books is 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{10}{4}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$
which agrees with the answer
$$\frac{3!}{2!}\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to multiply your answer by $3$ because as you mentioned there are three different ways to choose who gets $4$ books.